# OpenRefine Preferences

Tags: settings, openrefine

I'm trying to look for an OpenRefine preferences key-list but I don't seem able to find any.

I already tried googling for "openrefine preference keys" (and similar combinations). I tried looking at the project wiki and docs on [github](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/Documentation-For-Users) and on the [official page](https://openrefine.org/documentation.html) to no avail.

I'm particularly interested into setting OpenRefine client being opened by default to a specific browser (Chrome) rather than using system default one (Firefox), but I'd like to be able to browse all recognised preference keys in order to be able to "customize" OpenRefine as needed/liked.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can find a list of supported preferences in OpenRefine's documentation:

https://docs.openrefine.org/manual/running#preferences